# Setting TFS field as readonly based on area path

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have custom TFS form with a text field comment. I want this field to be readonly for most of the area paths except 4. How can I add condition to set the field as read only?
basically, when the area id is 1,2,3,4 the comment field should not be readonly else it should be readonly.
I tried the following, but it didn't work

```
<FIELD name="Comment" refname="test.test.comment" type="Integer">
     <WHENNOT field="System.AreaId" value="1">
              <READONLY />
            </WHENNOT>
            <WHENNOT field="System.AreaId" value="2">
              <READONLY />
            </WHENNOT>
            <WHENNOT field="System.AreaId" value="3">
              <READONLY />
            </WHENNOT>
            <WHENNOT field="System.AreaId" value="4">
              <READONLY />
            </WHENNOT>
</FIELD>
```

I dont want to write when conditions because these 4 are constant and I have about 40 other area ids which keeps increasing.

Answer (score 1):

No, "And" multiple "WHENNOT" conditions doesn't work. See: [Work Item state change rules in TFS - Any way to use "AND"s or "OR"s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747031/work-item-state-change-rules-in-tfs-any-way-to-use-ands-or-ors)

So, instead of using work item rules, you need to work with custom work item control. Determine when to set Comment filed to be readonly via using TFS API. Check this link for the details on how to work with custom work item control: https://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/